# Remove useless files from code base

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Is there any tool out there which could tell the useless files in the code base?

We have a big code base (PHP, HTML, CSS, JS files) and I want to be able to remove the not needed files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried human brain? :) Satisfaction guaranteed :)

Comment: What is the magic by which it would know something is useless?

Comment: @J0HN: Trying human brain for thousands of files and hundreds of folders isn't all that easy.

Comment: @Wrikken: Technology is great thing, checking if we have such tool already there.

Comment: I suppose you could use the profiler functionality of a debugger such as XDebug to build up enough data to determine all the files being used, but you can never be 100% sure you don't need one.  It might be some bit of functionality that only gets rarely used and never shows up in daily usage.

Comment: @Dev555 for technology to exist there should be some hint on how to separate used and unused files. So, if you have some idea on it - please post it. If you don't, the only way is to do it by hand. You can try renaming/deleting files and checking if everything go OK (e.g. running automated tests if you have some, or just opening a browser and checking all the pages)

Comment: @Dev555: not without specifying exactly what is needed. Running code-coverage with xdebug for PHP files is easy, but if you haven't written the tests to make sure all cases of use are accounted for it will be useless. Same case for css-coverage tools: you will have to do the work beforehand to tell it where to look.

Comment: @J0HN: Asked the question to see if any one else has the idea or implemented anything like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing deleting files and running your phpunit tests is a none starter.

If your files are not already in a version-control system - add them. Having the files in a version control system (such as svn or git) is crucial to allow you to recover from deleting any files that you thought were not being used but you later find out were.

Then, you can delete anything you think may not be being used, and if it doesn't affect the running of your application you can conclude that the files aren't used. If adverse effects show up - you can restore them from your repository with ease.

The above is most appropriate (probably) for frontend files (css, js, images). Any files you delete that are requested will show up in your webserver error log giving you a quick reference for files that nolonger exist that you need to restore.

For your php files, that's quite a bit more tricky, How did you arrive at a position where you have php files which you aren't using? Anyway you could for example:

- Use xdebug
- Enable profiling
- Use append mode (one profile)
- Use all the functions of your application

and you would then have a profile which includes all files you loaded. Scanning the generated profile for each php file in your codebase will give you some indication of which files you didn't use.

If you are only looking for unused files, don't be tempted to use code coverage analysis - it is very intensive and not the level of detail you're asking for.

A slightly less risky way would be to log whenever a file is loaded. e.g. put this at line one of each file:

```
<?php file_put_contents('/some/location/fileaccess.log', __FILE__, FILE_APPEND); ?>
```

and simply leave your application to be used for a while (days, weeks). Thereafter just scan that log, for any file that is named - remove the above line of code. For any that are not - delete (preferably after looking for the filename in your whole sourcecode and confirming it's nowhere).

OR: you could use a shutdown function which dumps the response of `get_included_files()` to a log file. This would allow you to achieve the same without editing all php files in your source tree.

Caveat: Be careful deleting your php files. Whereas a missing css/js/image will probably mean your application still works, a missing php file of course will have rather more impact :).

Answer (score 0):

If it is in Git why not delete the local file and then do a `git rm <file name>` to remove it from that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with everything said by @AD7six.

What you might like to try with PHP is to log the use of the files in someway (logging to flat file or database).

This technique does not have to be in place for long you can do it with an include and require_once at the top of each file.

That technique also works for javascript functions you can just print to the console each function, and then unit test your site. You can probably clean out a lot of redundant code that way.

The rest is not so easy, but version tracking is the way to go.